# split hdmi output signal into 4 displays

Tags: hdmi

If you are playing a 4 player split screen game, is there a way to split an HDMI signal into 4 to go to multiple displays, where each only shows a quarter of the display?

What about for older style connectors like RCA ones?

Loss if picture resolution not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

It will depend on the game and graphics card. Even if you have a graphics card capable of driving 4 simultaneous displays, most full-screen games will default to showing up on your primary display only. One potential workaround would be to put it in windowed mode and stretch it across your four displays.

If that doesn't work, the configuration utility for any gaming-focused graphics card will let you setup multiple displays so that Windows recognizes, e.g., 4 monitors as a single giant display. It has been a while since I've used a setup like this but as of about 10 years ago, AMD called it "HydraVision" and NVidia had "NView."

[image]

[image]